# Local Storage with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I  want to incorporate local storage in my phonegap code, where I want to save an array of data.

A part of my code reads :

```
       <div data-role="collapsibleset"> 
         <div  data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>LOGIN</h3>
            <form id="login-form" data-ajax="false" method="post">
                <label for="text-1">USERNAME:</label><input name="text-1"  id="text-1" type="text" value="subin">
                <label for="password">PASSWORD:</label><input name="password"  id="password" type="password" value="passwordx">

                <input type="button" data-theme="b" name="submit" id="submit" value="enter" data-iccon="plus">
            </form>
         </div>
```

now I want to capture the username and password, and use JSON.Stringify and use that to store the data. However I am so sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer this snippet:

```js
var userObj = {
  user: 'User',
  password: 'password'
};
var setLS = document.getElementById('setLS');
var getLS = document.getElementById('getLS');
var setter = function() {
  localStorage.setItem('userObj', JSON.stringify(userObj));
  console.log('userObj set in localStorage');
};
var getter = function() {
  var storage = localStorage.getItem('userObj');
  console.log(JSON.parse(storage));
};
setLS.addEventListener('click', setter);
getLS.addEventListener('click', getter);
```

```html
<button id="setLS">Set LocalStorage</button>
<button id="getLS">Get LocalStorage</button>
```

You can refer this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/w6Lg27a2/) as well..